# How can I get gold in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

I know next ways of obtaining gold:

- winning games in Arena
- winning 3 game in "Play" mode gives 10g
- daily quest gives some gold
- passing tutorial
- getting all heroes to level 10 gives 100g

Last one is not stated anywhere and isn't obvious so I wonder if there are other "hidden" options to receive gold?

Comment: some daily quests gives a diffrent amount than 40g

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several (non-repeatable) ways to win gold in Hearthstone, which can be found on [HearthHead's achievements page](http://www.hearthhead.com/achievements)

- Win 1000 games in any mode (300 gold)
- Win 100 games in any mode (300 gold)
- Defeat every Expert AI Hero (100 gold)
- Collect every card in the basic set (this is equivalent to leveling all heroes to 10) (100 gold)
- Collect every card in the expert set (100 gold)
- Unlock every hero (100 gold)

The repeatable ways to earn gold are:

- Win games in Arena (amount varies)
- Win games in Play (10 gold for 3 wins)
- Complete [daily quest](http://www.hearthhead.com/quests) (amount varies, 40-100 gold)
- Real money transaction

Comment: Real money transactions do not directly earn you gold, but can be substituted for gold. Currently there is no functional difference, but that may not always be true. That is to say, we don't know if in the future there may be something gold can buy that money can not.